# C++ reading random lines of txt?

Tags: c++

I am running C++ code where I need to import data from txt file. 
The text file contains 10,000 lines. Each line contains n columns of binary data.

The code has to loop 100,000 times, each time it has to randomly select a line out of the txt file and assign the binary values in the columns to some variables.

What is the most efficient way to write this code? should I load the file first into the memory or should I randomly open a random line number?

How can I implement this in C++?

Comment: Try memory mapping. If all columns are fixed-width, you get crazy-fast random access.

Comment: This sounds like you're going to read each record from your file an average of 10 times (loop 100,000 times over only 10,000 records). Can you handle all ten instances when you get to every record, and read your file directly in linear order? Or is the complete randomness of it extremely important for your project?

Comment: @kerrek-sb: column are not fixed width
@androo: no, not a homework. I wish it was.

Comment: @sarnold:  Complete randomness is required.

Comment: do you plan to load the whole file into memory? If so load the whole file first then sort. Is the size of the file small compared to memory? If so load the whole file. If you plan to only have one line (or a small cache) in memory then it may be worth randomly loading lines and throwing them away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To randomly access a line in a text file, all lines need to have the same byte-length. If you don't have that, you need to loop until you get at the correct line. Since this will be pretty slow for so much access, better just load it into a `std::vector` of `std::string`s, each entry being one line (this is easily done with `std::getline`). Or since you want to assign values from the different columns, you can use a `std::vector` with your own struct like

```
struct MyValues{
  double d;
  int i;
  // whatever you have / need
};

std::vector<MyValues> vec;
```

Which might be better instead of parsing the line all the time.

With the `std::vector`, you get your random access and only have to loop once through the whole file.

Comment: "To randomly access a line in a text file, all lines need to have the same byte-length." - unless you build a randomly-accessible index first (e.g. on Linux, `std::vector<off64_t>` suitable for `lseek64`).  Anyway, as the number of lines is relatively small, and building an index is no less work than creating the `vector` of `std::string`, this is a solid answer... +1.

Comment: @Tony: Right, I also thought of something like an offset-vector, but then I wondered about the seeking on-disk every read so I didn't put it in my answer. Still, now it's in a comment and all is fine. :P

Comment: Well, almost fine - everyone's ignoring the "...each time it has to randomly select a line out of the txt file and assign the binary values in the columns to some variables." - that column extraction might be more efficiently done once when populating the `vector`, so the `value_type` might not best be `std::string`... but the question lacks details to provide any concrete suggestions....  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

10K lines is a pretty small file.
If you have, say, 100 chars per line, it will use the HUGE amount of 1MB of your RAM.

Load it to a `vector` and access it the way you want.

Comment: 1M is not a HUGE amount of ram. On most machine used by any company that would be small. For a home laptop it my be HUGE.

Comment: @Martin: I think you missed the sarcasm ;-).

Answer (score 0):

maybe not THE most efficient, but you could try this:

```
int main() {
    //use ifstream to read
    ifstream in("yourfile.txt");

    //string to store the line
    string line = "";

    //random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        in.seekg(rand() % 10000);
        in>>line;
        //do what you want with the line here...
    }
}
```

Im too lazy right now, but you need to make sure that you check your ifstream for errors like end-of-file, index-out-of-bounds, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're taking 100,000 samples from just 10,000 lines, the majority of lines will be sampled. Read the entire file into an array data structure, and then randomly sample the array. This avoids file seeking entirely.

The more common case is to sample only a small subset of the file's data. To do that, assuming the lines are different length, seek to random points in the file, skip to the next newline (for example `cin.ignore( numeric_limits< streamsize >::max(), '\n' )`, and then parse the subsequent text.